# Error in #include <unity.h> with PlatformIO

Tags: unit-testing, esp8266, platformio

I am a newbie. I'm trying to test the basic Led Project with PlatformIO. The board I'm using is MCU8266. I got stuck on the path with "Unity.h", but I don't know where it is. I have found its library on the PlatformIO's lib, but it's not included.
Here are the file platformio.ini and the error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce8UT.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yBES.jpg)

Comment: Have you read the PlatformIO documentation on how to use libraries?

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/projectconf/section_env_library.html) on how to install library on PlatformIO.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error following the [documentation](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/tutorials/core/unit_testing_blink.html) at first, and simply restarting the vscode works for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to intall `unity.h` first.

Just click the test icon at the bottom and it should be installed automatically

[image: Test Icon]

<sup>Test Icon</sup>